# Using a list inside a map (Java)

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I'm using a HashMap in which I use an ArrayList as a value.

Like this:

```
Map<Movie, List<Grades>> gradedMovies = new HashMap();
```

I'm trying to create a method with which I could iterate through the values to see if a key(movie) already exists. If it does, I would like to add a new value(grade) into the list that is assigned to the particular key(movie). Something like this:

```
public void addGrade(Movie movie, Grade grade) {
// stuff here }
```

Ultimately I wan't to be able to print a Map which would display the Movies and its' grades after they've been added to the map.

How is this accomplished? Or is my whole approach (using a Map) totally wrong?

Thanks for any assistance. (This is homework)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the approach that I can see. What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to add Grades for the specific Movie since HashMaps(as I just realized) don't seem to have indexes.

Comment: If this is homework I suggest you present some code that we can look at, and propose enhancements for, rather than just asking us to give you a solution.

Comment: @Mark you have `containsKey(<key>)` to see if the key's there and `get(<key>)` to get the value for that key you don't need an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the right path, just make sure your movie object implements `equals` and `hashCode` so it can work as a true key for the hash map.

If you want pretty printing just implement the toString method.

```
public void addGrade(Movie movie, Grade grade) {
    if (!gradedMovies.containsKey(movie)) { 
        gradedMovies.put(movie, new ArrayList()); 
    }
    gradedMovies.get(movie).add(grade);
}
```

hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: FYI, this is what Multimap does. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like that:

```
public void addGrade(Movie movie, Grade grade) {
    if (!gradedMovies.containsKey(movie)) {
        gradedMovies.put(movie, new ArrayList<Grade>());
    }
    gradedMovies.get(movie).add(grade);
}
```

You need override the method `equals`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you're looking for an index particularly - the *point* of a `Map` is that you can look up entries by their keys.

So as a starting point, the first line of your `addGrade` method could look like

```
List<grades> grades = gradedMovies.get(movie);
```

and you can hopefully take it from there.  (Remember to look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) to see what happens if the map doesn't contain the given movie yet...)

Comment: Okay, I didn't quite understand how does one use the keys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I could iterate through the values to see if a key(movie) already exists

You don't need to iterate through the map, just call `gradedMovies.containsKey( movieToCheck )`.

Note that when using `Movie` as a key you should provide a sensible implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing ok! but you should consider a couple of things:

While finding a value on the map, your Movie object has to override **equals** and hashChode. Java will always use the equals method on comparations, mainly when it comes to automatic ones (like verifying if a list contains an item or, in this case, if a key value is equal to a given one). **Remember that equals defines the uniquity of an item**, so you should make a comparation based on a particulary unique attribute, like an identification number or (for this case) it's name.

To print the map, **iterate** over the keySet, either manually (**enhanced "for" loop**) or with an iterator (which can be obtained directly through the **.iterator()** method). For each movie, you print the list of grades in a similar fashion.

I don't know if you're familiar with String printing, but some special combination of characters can be added to a String to give it some sort of formatting. For example:

- \n will insert a line break
- \t is a tabulation

Hope this helps to erase some doubts. Good luck!.

Comment: @Mark No problemo :). I forgot to mention that like movies, Grades should also implement equals and hashCode if you want to make sure that a grade is added only one time to a list. Equals lets you use a call like `gradeList.contains(grade)`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). That is exactly what it does.

```
private Multimap<Movie, Grade> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

public void addGrade(Movie movie, Grade grade){
   map.put(movie, grade);
}
```

It will take care of creating the list for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addGrade(Movie movie, Grade grade) {

boolean found = false;
for(Movie m : gradedMovies.keyset()) {
    // compare the movies
    if(/* match on movies */) {
        gradedMovies.get(m).add(grade);
        found = true;
    }
}
if(!found) {
    gradedMovies.put(movie, new ArrayList().add(grade));
}
}
```

Comment: What is the point of iterating instead of using Map.get? That's just more code and slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
gradedMovies.containsKey(movie);

    for(Map.Entry<Movie,List<Grades>> entry : gradedMovies.entrySet()){
            Movie key = entry.getKey();
       }
```